# C# Return Generic List/IEnumerable, how does it works?

Tags: c#, list, generics, ienumerable

I have a method which returns me a list(IEnumerable) of cars..

(Works fine with Returntypes `IEnumerable<Car>` and `List<Car>`):

```
public IEnumerable<Car> GetCars(string xml)
{
    var myResultList;

     XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
     myResultList = doc.Descendants().Descendants("dict").Select(
     x => new Employee
     {
         Id = x.Elements("string").ElementAt(0).Value,
         Prename = x.Elements("string").ElementAt(1).Value,
         Name = x.Elements("string").ElementAt(2).Value,
         Initials = x.Elements("string").ElementAt(3).Value
    }
    );

    IEnumerable<Car> enumerable = myResultList;
    return enumerable;

    //---

    //or as a List if it's better?
    List<Car> asList = enumerable.ToList();
    //then: return asList
}
```

Now I would like to make this Method **generic**.
Every IEnumerable Type / Or List Type should be able.

Something like this - thats just pseudo code, as I don't know how it works;

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData(string xml)
{
    var myResultList;

    //...myResultList.. will be filled here (unnecessary) 

    IEnumerable<T> enumerable = myResultList;
    return enumerable;

    //---

    //or as a List if it's better?
    List<T> asList = enumerable.ToList();
    //then: return asList
}
```

I hope my question is clear enough.. Just imagine you would have an other Type like *House* instead of *Car* but u wanted to use the same method for every type.

How can I achieve that? Help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Added the Code which fills "myResultsList"

EDIT 2:
2 XML's which should work on same method:

```
 <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>DataType</key>
    <string>Employee</string>
    <key>8000</key>
    <dict>
      <key>MitarbeiterNo</key>
      <string>8000</string>
      <key>Vorname</key>
      <string>Walter</string>
      <key>Name</key>
      <string>Walter Lohner Stans</string>
      <key>Initialien</key>
      <string>MAL</string>
    </dict>
    <key>8001</key>
    <dict>
      <key>MitarbeiterNo</key>
      <string>8001</string>
      <key>Vorname</key>
      <string>Motorrad</string>
      <key>Name</key>
      <string> Meierskappel</string>
      <key>Initialien</key>
      <string>MAM</string>
    </dict>
    <key>8004</key>
    <dict>
      <key>MitarbeiterNo</key>
      <string>8004</string>
      <key>Vorname</key>
      <string>Hanspeter</string>
      <key>Name</key>
      <string>Altenbürger AG  Horgen</string>
      <key>Initialien</key>
      <string>FH</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

and

```
 <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>DataType</key>
    <string>Agent</string>
    <key>7000</key>
    <dict>
      <key>AgentNo</key>
      <string>7000</string>
      <key>Initialien</key>
      <string>VW</string>
      <key>Namen</key>
      <string>Walter Gnos Vertretungen  Vevey</string>
    </dict>
    <key>7001</key>
    <dict>
      <key>AgentNo</key>
      <string>7001</string>
      <key>Namen</key>
      <string>Miller GmbH Bern</string>
    </dict>
    <key>7002</key>
    <dict>
      <key>AgentNo</key>
      <string>7002</string>
      <key>Initialien</key>
      <string>MAL</string>
      <key>Namen</key>
      <string>Walter Lohner Stans</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: You can achieve it very much like you've demonstrated

Comment: You'll need to show us how you're populating `myResultList` from the XML string.

Comment: Your code looks fine, the key point is now how you fill out myResultList, which really depends on what is in xml.

Comment: I agree with @JustinHarvey.  It all depends on how you are trying to get the objects from the data source.

Comment: In most cases it is not the best practice to wait for the whole list to be assembled before using the items. You should have a look at the keyword yield to improve your code instead of returning the whole list at once with ToList(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: I added the code, where you can see how I'm populating `myResultList`, here I'm working with Employee. Car was just an easy Example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is the `<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string xml)
```

then you call it as:

```
var data = obj.GetData<House>(xml);
```

where the `<House>` tells `GetData` what the `T` is for that call. Note that inside `GetData<T>` you can use `typeof(T)` to get the `Type`, which might be necessary if you are using `XmlSerializer` or similar for the deserialization.

Note that in some cases it can be *really handy* to use generics, and it some others it can actually makes things problematic - so you might *also* want to consider whether it might not be more appropriate to use:

```
public IEnumerable GetData(Type type, string xml)
```

i.e. pass the `Type` in as a regular parameter. This can be useful if you are doing a lot of work with reflection, where generics become tricky. But to emphasize: both generic and non-generic solutions are reasonable and valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I put the code above, where u can see how I'm filling myResultsList. In that case I will need to work with Reflection? Get Type, Create Instance, Fill Properties by the string?

Comment: @eMi the problem is: the code in your edit is not "generic" - it is specialized to a particular type. If you want to replace that with a "generic" solution, you'd need a "generic" way to read that data. That *could* mean reflection (with some mechanism to indicate how the data should be mapped from xml nodes to properties/fields, typically via attributes) - however, I would first query whether it is *sensible* to look for a generic solution to a non-generic problem.

Comment: my code isn't "generic" yeah, cause I don't know how to make it generic. But I will try to find that out. It must be a generic solution, because there are 10 XML Files, with very similiar definitions, there is everywhere the same tag and a "logic" behind. The only thing, that isn't the same, are the Objects and other Properties. Once it can be  an Employee, once a Car.

Comment: @eMi which makes me wonder if something like `XmlSerializer` might help. Can you make the layout clear? It *looks* like all your xml elements are `<string>` ...?

Comment: I provided the 2 XML Examples, which I'm using. One is of Type `Employee` and the other one of Type `Agent`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do. You can paste this code in a Console Application:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bar { }

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var foos = new List<Foo>
                           {
                               new Foo { Id =1, Bar = new Bar()},
                               new Foo { Id =2, Bar = null},
                               new Foo { Id =3, Bar = new Bar()},
                               new Foo { Id =4, Bar = null},
                           };

            var xml = ToXml(foos);

            var result = GetData<List<Foo>>(xml);
        }

        private static string ToXml(List<Foo> foos)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(foos.GetType());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
            ser.Serialize(writer, foos);

            string xml = sb.ToString();
            return xml;
        }

        public static T GetData<T>(string xml)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            object obj = ser.Deserialize(reader);

            T result = (T)obj;

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```